# Remove data array JS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am working on creating a file where data can be read from a JSON file.

I can add new names to the file but I am unable to delete. When I enter a name to delete it actually adds the name to the file.

Why is it adding & not deleting? The objective is to be able to delete a specific name from the list that will be generated.

Thank you in advance! Here is my code with comments on what I am attempting to do.

```
// POST request to add to JSON & XML files
router.post('/post/json', function(req, res) {

    // Function to read in a JSON file, add to it & convert to XML
    function appendJSON(obj) {

        // Read in a JSON file
        var JSONfile = fs.readFileSync('Staff.json', 'utf8');

        // Parse the JSON file in order to be able to edit it 
        var JSONparsed = JSON.parse(JSONfile);

        // Add a new record into country array within the JSON file    
        JSONparsed.member.push(obj);

        // Beautify the resulting JSON file
        var JSONformated = JSON.stringify(JSONparsed, null, 4);

        // Delte a specific entry from JSON file
        var i = member.indexOf(" ");
        if (i != -1) {
            member.splice(i,1);
        }

        // Write the updated JSON file back to the system 
        fs.writeFileSync('Staff.json', JSONformated);

        // Convert the updated JSON file to XML     
        var XMLformated = js2xmlparser.parse('staff', JSON.parse(JSONformated));

        // Write the resulting XML back to the system
        fs.writeFileSync('Staff.xml', XMLformated);
    }

    // Call appendJSON function and pass in body of the current POST request
    appendJSON(req.body);

    // Re-direct the browser back to the page, where the POST request came from
    res.redirect('back');
});
```

Here is an example of the `JSON` file

```
{ 
    "member": [ 
        { 
            "Full_Name": "", 
            "Address": "", 
            "Gender": "",     
            "Phone_Number": "" 
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Return_value) function removes the item from the array and returns the deleted item. So if you want to delete an item by an attribute from your `JSON` like `Full_Name` you have to find the index of the item first.

```
var nameToSearch = "MyName";
var itemIndex = -1;
for(var i = 0; i < JSONparsed.member.length; i++) {
    if(JSONparsed.member[i].Full_Name === nameToSearch) {
        itemIndex = i;
    }
}
```

And then you can delete the item like you did.

```
if (itemIndex != -1) {
    JSONparsed.member.splice(itemIndex,1);
}
```

The problem you most likely had was that the `itemIndex` was allways -1 as `indexOf` did not know which attribute to check and just checks for the whole object.

Also the following lines have to be after the code above. (So after any changes you make to the `json`)

```
// Beautify the resulting JSON file
var JSONformated = JSON.stringify(JSONparsed, null, 4);
```

I also recomend reading [this turtorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp) about javascript debugging. It makes your live a lot easyier to find mistakes.

Comment: Am I better to use the above or use a delete method here?

Comment: my bad, I always get `splice` and `slice` confused.  Turns out `splice` does modify in place :)

Comment: The splice method returns "An array containing the deleted elements." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Return_value

Comment: @baao ups my mistake. I changed my answer

Comment: @Dr.Fre Thanks guys but for some reason it is still adding the information onto the end of the file instead of deleting it. Can't figure out what I am doing wrong here

Comment: @ThisisD do you want to add it at the index of the item that has " " as content? because this line `JSONparsed.member.push(obj);` just adds the `obj` to the end of the array

Comment: @DrFre I hope I word this correctly but I have a object called member in the Json file, with a list of arrays containing information on people. I want to be able to delete arrays, say for when people leave the group I want to delete their information. I am able to add new people by writing the following code JSONparsed.member.push(obj); But for example I want to call up any person at any time and delete their record. Say call up "Sean" and delete him from the records

Comment: @ThisisD shouldn't `member` be an array? can you add a `json` example to you question.

Comment: @Dr.Fre Yes sorry!

Comment: @Dr.Fre As you can probably tell I am very new to this....Here is an example from the JSON file  {
    "member": [
        {
            "Full_Name": "",
            "Address": "",
            "Gender": "",
            "Phone_Number": ""
        },

Comment: @Dr.Fre Thank you for all your help

Comment: @ThisisD no problem. leave an upvote if you think it's a good anwser and I really recommend the turtorial at the end of my answer. It's short but debugging is the ultimate tool when it comes to finding errors.